# Custom taxonomy archive template not recognised

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I have a custom post type, named 'products', it has a custom taxonomy that is called 'collections'.
This is how I have registered the taxonomy.

```
$productTaxonomyArgs = [
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'description' => __('Product category', 'byronposttypes'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => __('collections', 'byronposttypes'),
        'with_front' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES
    ],
];

register_taxonomy('collections', 'products', $productTaxonomyArgs);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('collections', 'products');
```

I have created a taxonomy template by the name taxonomy-collections.php.

```
<?php

get_header();
$post = null;
echo '<h1>taxonomy-collections.php</h1>'; //Echo this to make sure the template works.
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) { //rest of the code
```

When I navigate to `/collections/lifestyle` (lifestyle is one of the taxonomy terms), the `<title>` is 'Lifestyle Archives - [sitename]', so Wordpress does recognise the url as a taxonomy term archive. The problem is, that it doesn't even echo `<h1>taxonomy-collections.php</h1>` to the page. That makes me assume that the `taxonomy-collections.php` is not recognised by Wordpress.
Any idea as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot for reading and helping!
I found out that Wordpress is falling back to index.php. But `is_tax();` returns `true`. Not a single one of the taxonomy-specific templates seem to work (`taxonomy.php`, `taxonomy-collection.php` and `taxonomy-collection-lifestyle.php`), not even `archive.php` will work.

Comment: have you tried flushing permalinks?? Go to wordpress settings and save permalinks.

Comment: I have, this does not solve my problem. Navigating to /collections/lifestyle sets the page title to 'Lifestyle Archive', which I think would imply Wordpress using the right rewrite rules. Even using `taxonomy.php` does not work.

Comment: If you check the body classes what does it show? This usually gives away which file is being loaded

Comment: It shows the following classes: `archive tax-collections term-lifestyle term-99 logged-in wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-5.0.1 vc_responsive`. I also tried creating archive.php to see if that would work, but that also had no effect. The header and footer _are_ included when loading the page

Comment: I have found out that Wordpress falls back to index.php (should've tested that earlier). I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what I was doing wrong. Apparently you have to place archive pages in the root folder of your theme.
I placed them in a subfolder called templates. This works for page templates with a template name, but not for `taxonomy.php`, `archive.php`, `single.php` etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, its working for me ..

```
 function add_collection_taxonomies() {
        $productTaxonomyArgs = array(
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'description' => __('Product category', 'byronposttypes'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => __('collections', 'byronposttypes'),
            'with_front' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES
        ),
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('collections', 'products');
    register_taxonomy('collections', 'product', $productTaxonomyArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it doesn't seem to change anything, `taxonomy-collections.php` still does not seem to work as a template file. The only differences I see between our code snippets is that you use `array` in stead of `[ ]`, and you switched around `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` and `register_taxonomy()`. Did I miss something? I did re-save the permalinks after trying this, by the way